# Comparing two strings using strtok()

Tags: c, string, file, strtok

I need to compare strings from two text files. While separating the strings using `strtok()` (for either file), I have a problem while referring to sentences from two files, using `strtok()`, as they are colliding.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <conio.h>

int main()
{
    FILE *fp,*fp1,*fp2;
    fp=fopen("inp1.txt","r");
    fp1=fopen("inp2t.txt","r");

    int f;
    char *a,*b,*chk;
    char buffer[500],buf[5000];

    while(fgets(buf,5000,fp1));
    {
        chk= (char *)strtok (buf," ");

        while(chk!=NULL)
        {
            rewind(fp);
            f=0;

            while(fgets(buffer,500,fp))
            {
                a= (char *) strtok(buffer,"\t");
                b= (char *) strtok(NULL,"\n");

                if(stricmp(a,chk)==0)
                {
                    printf("%s",b);
                    printf(" ");
                    f=1;
                }
            }

            if(f==0)
            {
                printf("%s",chk);
                printf(" ");
            }

            chk= (char *) strtok(NULL," ");                
        }
    }
    fclose(fp);
    fclose(fp1);

    getch();
    return 0;                    
}
```

How can I fix this code so that I'm able to extract tokens from both input files?

Comment: Welcome to C. Basically, you need a different strtok function, like `strtok_s`, that supports re-entry.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

strtok() uses global internal values, which will collide.  Use strtok_s() to prevent that, as that function takes a reference variable that will keep the two instances separate.

Comment: As far as I know, `strtok_s` is not part of the standard library. You'd want `strtok_r` on GNU. In my opinion, it's probably better to find another way than `strtok*` altogether.

Comment: @netcoder: `strtok_s` is part of ISO/IEC 9899:2011 (C11) standard

Comment: @user411313: Ah I see. It still doesn't seem to be supported by GCC 4.7 though.

Comment: @netcoder You have to define `__STDC_LIB_EXT1__` as 1 before including `string.h`. If it's not defined, or defined as 0, these functions aren't available.

Comment: @DanielFischer: Just checked out with GCC 4.7.1 and GLIBC 2.16 (both being the latest), there's still no declaration of a `strtok_s` function anywhere in the libraries, or the changelog for that matter.

Comment: @netcoder Aha, then gcc doesn't provide these functions, pity, but they're optional ("This annex speciﬁes a series of optional extensions"), so that's allowed.

Comment: Actually, that was a typo; I meant strtok_r (GNU), which I have used.  I won't edit the post, because it would make the comments confusing...

Comment: Thank you everyone, although I think, I will mess up with strtok_s() or strtok_r(). if in case I use fscanf() (as suggested by 'Jerry Coffin') how can I skip characters like, ',' , '.' etc.? and @Jerry Coffin, what does %4999s stand for?

Answer (score 2):

`strtok` uses a static pointer to the string being parsed, so only one invocation of it can be active at any given time.

I'd probably just use:

```
char buffera[5000];
char bufferb[5000];

fscanf(fp, "%4999s", buffera);
// ...
fscanf(fp, "%4999s", bufferb);
```

Answer (score 0):

strtok has an internal state that remembers the last position. strtok_r() is a reentrant version of strtok(). Check if it is available on your platform and use that.